# angular2 select disable first element

Tags: angular

I have a select component like this:

```
<select name="typeSelection" materialize="material_select" 
        [(ngModel)]="trainingplan.type" >
  <option [ngValue] = "null" disabled selected>Please choose a type</option>
  <option [ngValue]="type" *ngFor="let type of firebaseService.trainingTypes">
    {{type.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

I want the first option to be disabled so that the user sees this hint. But instead of this, the first entry of the "trainingTypes" gets selected. I guess this is because Angular doesn't know which one to select because of the binding maybe and so it takes the first one. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `trainingplan.type` would need to be set to `null` but as far as I know `[ngValue]` with null will only work after the next update.

You would need to choose a different value for the first option and set `trainingplan.type` to this value. You can remove the `selected` attribute.